# Unexpected result in Enum.HasFlag

Tags: c#, enums, .net-4.0

I recently encountered an error in my code where I was attempting to "dismantle" an enum flag into an array of its constituent values, but unexpected results would sometimes be returned.

Long story short, certain integer types assigned to my values appear to cause some behaviour that is unexpected (well, to me at least). I boiled down the issue into the following unit test:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    ITEM1 = 30104,
    ITEM2 = 30201,
}

[TestClass]
public class EnumFlagTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SanityCheck()
    {
        var flag2 = TestEnum.ITEM2;

        Assert.IsFalse(flag2.HasFlag(TestEnum.ITEM1));
    }
}
```

I did not expect `flag2` to report that it "has the flag" of `ITEM1`, as I do not believe that it does.

I guess that it has something to do with the Int32 values I've assigned to the items, but please could someone explain what's going on?? - Why does this test fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't use `HasFlag` for a non flags-based enum... and a flags-based enum should use a separate bit for each flag.

The problem is indeed because of the values. Writing this in binary, you've got:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    ITEM1 = 0b111010110011000,
    ITEM2 = 0b111010111111001
}
```

Note how every bit that's set in `ITEM1` is also set in `ITEM2` - and that's what's checked by `HasFlag`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.7#System_Enum_HasFlag_System_Enum_):

> Returns:
>
> `true` if the bit field or bit fields that are set in `flag` are also set in the current instance; otherwise, `false`.

That *is* true for `TestEnum.ITEM2.HasFlag(TestEnum.Item1)`, hence it returns true.

Answer (score 2):

The `HasFlag` method is a bitwise check and the bits of `ITEM1` match up with `ITEM2`:

Note that `ITEM2` contains all the same `1`s that `ITEM1` has:

```
ITEM1: 111010110011000
ITEM2: 111010111111001
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are wanting to use "Bit flags" - a collection of boolean values that are easy to merge.

To do that, each flag needs one bit set and the bit needs to be in a unique location.

But it is valid to combine flags to cover common groupings.

One technique I learned here on StackOverflow is to set the first flag and then bit-shift for the rest of the flags.  Something like this:

```
[Flags]
enum color {
  none = 0,
  red = 1,                           // 0b0001
  yellow = red << 1,                 // 0b0010
  blue = yellow << 1,                // 0b0100

  primaries = red | yellow | blue,   // 0b0111  

  green = yellow | blue,             // 0b0110
  purple = red | blue,               // 0b0101
  orange = red | yellow              // 0b0011
}
```

with this, you can

```
Assert.IsFalse(Color.green.HasFlag(color.red));
Assert.IsTrue(Color.primary.HasFlag(color.red));
```

I hope that clears things up for you!

- Note, the code here is largely pseudo-code; there may be syntax errors.  The concept is, however, sound.